# register windows form in castle.windsor

Tags: c#, telerik, castle

I'm using `telerik` in windows form, so i want to register windows forms in `castle.windsor`, but windows form inherited from `Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm` i cant register this forms.
when my form inherited from "Form" then i don't use from telerik, this form is being registered successfully.

**this code register successfully**

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var container = Bootstrapper.WireUp();//return windsoerContainer
        container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<Form1>()
                .BasedOn<Form>().LifestyleTransient());
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(container.Resolve<Form1>());
    }
}
```

---

**this code Does not work**

```
enter code here
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var container = Bootstrapper.WireUp();//return windsoerContainer
        container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<FrmLogin>()
                .BasedOn<RadForm>().LifestyleTransient());
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(container.Resolve<FrmLogin>());
    }
}

public partial class FrmLogin : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm//frm login
{
    private readonly ICategoryService _categoryService;
    public FrmLogin(ICategoryService categoryService)
    {
        _categoryService = categoryService;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

### }

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static IWindsorContainer WireUp()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component.For<TransactionInterceptor>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
        container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<CategoryService>()
            .BasedOn<IService>()
            .WithServiceFromInterface()
            .LifestylePerWebRequest().Configure(a=>a.Interceptors<TransactionInterceptor>()));

        container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<CategoryRepository>()
            .BasedOn<IRepository>()
            .WithServiceFromInterface()
            .LifestylePerWebRequest());

        container.Register(Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<EfUnitOfWork>().LifestylePerWebRequest());

        container.Register(Component.For<CrmDbContext>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
        ServiceLocator.SetCurrent(new WindsorServiceLocator(container));
        return container;
    }
}
```

Thank you for helping me...

Comment: yes this forms are in the same Assembly. and are public

Comment: this line has error :            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(container.Resolve<FrmLogin>());

Comment: when i want to run form,throws exception

Comment: Please update your post to include the source code of `FrmLogin`.

Comment: I updated quesions.

Comment: Try `.BasedOn<Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm>()`

Comment: Is `ICategoryService` registered with the container?

Comment: I used this, but did not work

Comment: this picture show that These are registered
 http://gift.5bazar.ir/Untitled.png

Comment: Doesn't that show `FrmLogin / RadForm` is registered as `Singleton*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem is enough 
**

> .LifestyleSingleton()

**

```
           var container = Bootstrapper.WireUp();//return windsoerContainer
        container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<FrmLogin>()
            .BasedOn<RadForm>().LifestyleSingleton());
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(container.Resolve<FrmLogin>());
```